# Which scripture deals with horoscope matching for marriage?

Tags: marriage, astrology

What is the pramaanam (reference) for dashama (10) poruthams (matching), listed [here](https://www.trsiyengar.com/id45.shtml)?

What are the exact rules to be followed when comparing the boy's and girl's horoscopes?

Since horoscope is completely dependent on place and time of birth, is there any way to verify the authenticity of janma patrika (birth chart) ?

Answer (score 3):

[Brihat Parashara Hora Shastra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brihat_Parashara_Hora_Shastra) written by *Sage Parashara* is considered the root text of Hindu astrology. It does not contain any references to 'horoscope matching'.

The [synastrical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astrological_compatibility) methods that you mention are some of the many techniques developed by astrologers for the purpose of analysing compatibility. These does not have any root in the scriptures. Some techniques get more famous than the others e.g. *Ashtakoota* matching is widely used in North India. Some astrologers use multilple techniques at once for horoscope matching.