# Are there mention of Zodiac signs in Mahabharata?

Tags: krishna, astrology, vyasa, mahabharata

Are there mention of Zodiac signs **by name**, in Mahabharata?

If yes please cite the verses.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there is mention of Zodiac signs in Mahabharata.

One such reference is present in [Mahabharata: Vana Parva: Markandeya-Samasya Parva](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03199.htm):

> A gift also that is made while the Sun is on the solstitial points, one again that is made on the last day of the Sun's path through **Libra**, **Aries**, **Gemini**, **Virgo**, and **Pisces**, a gift again during eclipses of the Moon and the Sun, produce merit that is inexhaustible.

Here is the Sanskrit verse and Hindi translation from Volume 2 (page #1393) of Unabridged Mahabharata by Gitapress:

> [image: Volume 2 (page #1393) of Unabridged Mahabharata by Gitapress]

Comment: Can you please give the verse number of Mahabharata??

Comment: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/49239/22253

Comment: Added Sanskrit verse.. @MrGreenGold

Comment: no where does it mention the rashis.

Comment: It says Uttarayana and Dakshinayana. It has no direct reference to Rashis. This is the problem with translations they add their own things and interpret it in their own ways

Comment: "Uttarayana and Dakshinayana" -- where it's mentioned?..Sanskrit verse mentions only Aynas and as u know there are two ayanas, u just translated it to Uttarayana and Dakshinayana.. similarly why u r not translating Vishuve and Sadsitimukheshu? if it's translation issue then u hv to provide diff meaning for each word..

Comment: Okay... u already hv answer here .. https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/49248/12304

Comment: I dont think you know the context here, ayana in this context has no other meaning than Uttarayana and Dakshinayana. Basically its only mentioning tropical equinox and solistice points. It's not the same as sidereal Rashi.

Comment: My question to be specific is are Rashis mentioned by name in Mahabharata. By name, not through some kndirect reference which can mean other things.

Comment: That other question is also asked by me, and it just says Purana saays it, without explaining why it's called shadasheeti

Comment: See Uttarayana is automatically assumed to be Makara Sankranti, which is not true. So this kind of translation is erroneous.

Comment: Please see this question there's some serious issues here. https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/36477/22253

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130435/discussion-between-mr-green-gold-and-yds).

Comment: please see chatroom

Answer (score 0):

Whilst a numder of sites that I've looked at online attests to a vedic astrology that uses the Zodiac, and which appears to be affirmed by [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindu_astrology) article, stating:

> Some western scholars believe that the horoscopic astrology practiced in the Indian subcontinent came from Hellenistic influences, post-dating the Vedic period and the Vedanga Jyotishya, one of the earliest texts about astronomy within the Vedas, dates from the last centuries BCE.

It also adds:

> However, this is a point of intense debate and many Indian scholars believe that Jyotisha developed independently although it may have interacted with Greek astronomy and Vedanga Jyotishya was compiled by 1200 BCE.

For example, we know of the cultural contact between the Hellenistic empire of Alexander the Great and India.  For example, [Gandhara](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gandhara#:%7E:text=Gandhara%20was%20an%20ancient%20kingdom,to%20the%20Gandhara%20grave%20culture.), is attested in the Rigveda (RV 1.126.7) and the Gandhāris are also mentioned in the Atharvaveda (AV 5.22.14),  and the Aitareya Brahmana refers to King Nagnajit of Gandhara. However, we know from excavations of Gandhara that a fusion of Greek & Buddhist sculpture - and hence culture - thrived there after Alexander the Great.

As to astrology, this [site](https://vedictime.com/en/library/rashi/mesha) explains:

> the ancient seers gave to this sign not only the name Meena (Pisces), which means fish, but also Antyaya, which means the end, and Yasha, which means glory.

and

> Dhanu (Sagittarius) is the centaur — a horse-like beast with a human upper part holding a bow and shooting an arrow toward the sky. The Sanskrit name for the sign refers merely to the bow, the arrow, and the shooting.

also

> Yavanacharya called Vrshchika (Scorpio) a deep opening in the earth

and

> Mesha (Aries) is the name given to the first sign of the zodiac. The Sanskrit word Mesha means a ram or sheep, but other synonyms given to it are more connotative. Aja means the unborn, Vishwa refers to the whole or the universe, Kriya stands for motion and activity, and Tambura is a musical instrument, while Adya implies the first primeval cause of the manifest universe. Though Aja means the unborn, it refers to the "unborn-but-existing-in-eternity."

Given the variant meanings and synonyms attached with the signs, it seems that an earlier Vedic astology was fused with that of the Greeks in terms of names, if not meaning.