# What is Shadashiti Sankranti?

Tags: astrology, sanskrit, mahabharata, astronomy

In [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/44517/22253) there is verse, which has word "Shadashiti Mukheshu" which has beem interpreted as Sankramana of Mithuna, Kanya, Dhanu and Meena.

[image]

---

### Is there authoritative reference which says what is Shadashiti Sankramana?

Comment: Can you correct Shadaseti to Shadashiti? Shadashiti means 86 (https://www.shabdkosh.com/dictionary/sanskrit-english/%E0%A4%B7%E0%A4%A1%E0%A4%B6%E0%A5%80%E0%A4%A4%E0%A4%BF/%E0%A4%B7%E0%A4%A1%E0%A4%B6%E0%A5%80%E0%A4%A4%E0%A4%BF-meaning-in-english)

Comment: @Rickross hey Rick, happy Dasara.

Comment: 3 different names of Sankramanas for Sun entering 3 kinds of Rasis: Chara, Sthira and Dviswabhava. All 4 mentioned here are Dviswabhava Rasis.

Comment: Hi thanks and same to you @MrGreenGold

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes , the  the term  Sadasiti is explained in [**Padama Purana**](https://archive.org/details/PadmaPuranaVol05BhumiAndPatalaKhandaPages15651937ENGMotilalBanarsidass1990_201901/Padma-Purana%20Vol-02%20-%20Srshti-Khanda%20-%20pages%20425-895%20ENG%20Motilal%20Banarsidass%201989/page/n455/mode/2up) - Vol. 1 - Shrishti Kanda - Chapter 77- Shloka 44.

> तासुयद्वाफलंब्रूमोलोकानांनिखिलंमुने |
> धनुर्मिथुनमीनेषुकन्यायां**षडशीतय** ||44||
>
> 44 We (i.e.  I)  shall , O Sage, (now) tell (you) all the fruit that
> is (obtained by one) on these (samkranti days) . (The samkranti days)
> on which the sun enters the Dhanu , Mithuna , Mina and Kanya (signs of
> zodiac) are called **Sadasiti.**

---

Sadasiti (षडशती) is one of the name  of the four passages of the sun from one zodiacal sign to the other. The Padma  Purana explanins that  Sadasiti. is the  period of passages of the sun in   Zodiac signs   Sagittarius , Gemini , Pisces , Virgo. i.e. when the  sun enters in  these    Zodiac signs   that transition or Sankranti is called as Sadasiti sankranti.

Similarely when the sun enters in   Zodiac signs    Taurus , Scorpius , Leo , Aquarius it is called as "Vishnupadi" and when in Aries, Libra it is called as "Vishuvat".

---

Comment: Swift Pushkar can you please explain why it's Shadasheti?? Why the name? Thank you

Comment: Also is this mentioned in Vedamga Jyothisha?? Any clue?

Comment: @MrGreenGold - Yeah I tried to find  etymology  of word Shadasiti but haven't found anything much.Meantime I will search again also looking in Joytisha texts and others.

Comment: Shadasiti means 86 (Shada 6 + Asiti 80).. somewhere i read it's every 86th day..

Comment: https://www.drikpanchang.com/planet/transit/surya-transit-date-time.html mentions transit into these 4 rashis every ~3months (as per modern calendar)..in some ancient calendar it should be 86 days that's why the name Shadasiti...

Comment: @YDS Thanks YDS

Comment: @YDS any idea?? https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/36477/22253

Comment: @SwiftPushkar any idea?? https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/36477/22253

Comment: @YDS - Yes , that's correct , I was already aware of that , but anyway thanks. Now we have to figure out from scripture that why the word is associated with the sankranti and what's the relation of no.86 with that.